# VS2010 Prof Website debugging incredibly slow

Tags: asp.net, performance, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Whenever I start up Debugmode in VS 2010 Prof it takes about 2-3 minutes before my browser(s) (tried with IE9 and newest Version of Chrome) start, if I want to stop debugging (shift-f6), it takes another 5 (f i v e) minutes before VS responds - it even grays out during that time.

I'm working on a Web Application of about 8MB excluding images ...

Debugging worked perfectly well until yesterday. Changes I made to my system until then: none.

I'm absolutely clueless, otherwise I'd provide more information, any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589338/slow-debugging-issue-in-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this question already and followed all the advice provided, it didn't help at all.

Comment: Dennis, try these related questions for some initial pointers [a](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3249449/451944) [b](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5006155/451944)

Comment: Thanks, it's not the Breakpoint issue, I already removed mine to check whether that's the problem. However, when I start the debugging process, CPU Usage jumps to 50%, effectively blocking one core. The CPU Usage only comes back down when the browser window opens (2 minutes later).

Comment: I just solved the problem, and yes - the solution is ridiculous.
1. Copy Project Folder
2. Load Project from there
3. Enjoy lightning-quick debugging!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing the following:

- Copied my entire Project Folder
- Started the Project from that location
- Enjoyed lightning-quick debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience. I fixed it by deleting the *.sdf and *.suo file, which were located near the *.sln file. VS generates new files if you restart it. I guess the *.sdf stores some Intellisence stuff and the suo breakpoints etc.

Answer (score 0):

For the Slow response times, here is my resolution by trial and error.   For VS 2010 , click "Tools" and "Options" then click "environment" and "AutoRecover" options.  I changed my Auto Saving options from every 30 seconds (default) to "20 Minutes" and Keep Auto Recover information for: 3 days instead of 7.  This drastically reduced my start and stopping debugging time to seconds.   Much better than 10 minutes for both.